# Sort pivot table filter alphabetically

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to have the different options in a filter for my pivot table to be sorted alphabetically, rather than how they are sorted here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0caa.png]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do it directly as a filter, but turned out the worked around wasn't harder than to move the field from Filters to Rows, sort it alphabetically and move it back to Filters.